# Do any Java libraries support batch sql query processing and proceeds even if any duplicate records exists in the batch?

Tags: java

Is batch processing possible in jdbi with the below condition?

If one insert query in the batch fails because of violating some constraints ( Primary key, foreign key violation.. etc) will it resume processing next set of insert queries in the batch?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)**

Comment: @gnat Restructured.

Comment: The examples [provided here](http://jdbi.org/) are just code.  You can do anything you want to in code by merely writing more code or changing the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for JDBI, you will have to deal with poor documentation and - I guess - trial and error. Specifically for Batch processing,

- It fails to clearly document when a commit is being executed: not (at the end or through auto commit), equal to the batch size, or some other customizable parameter. As it does the batch iteration for you, it is a very important fact.
- It does not document the method signature that is tagged with the SqlBatch annotation very well. Is the return type only `void`, or can it return an array that will provide me result status?

Looks like an interesting and promising API. But for me using it, I will be stuck with too many questions.